# Application continuously crashing, I've looked at every file and cannot seem to figure out what's going on

Tags: java, android

**Main Activity**

```
package com.wickham.android.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Setup the ActionBar and the Spinner in the ActionBar
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setSubtitle("Practical Android");
    getActionBar().setTitle("Splash");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit) {
        finish();
        return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

**Error Code**

```
2021-02-24 23:52:19.708 9309-9309/com.murach.splash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.murach.splash, PID: 9309
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.murach.splash/com.wickham.android.splash.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.wickham.android.splash.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Will you, by editing your post, show us the line 47 of com.wickham.android.splash.Splash?

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` because `getActionBar()` is
depricater and returning null and you're getting null pointer exception so maybe this will work.

and also use this

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: why would you want to use `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: It will support `getSupportActionBar() `

Comment: and you're sure this is available in the latest packages, making use of androidX ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to extend your Activity from AppCompatActivity:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity{
}
```

don't use Activity or ActionBarActivity. I suggest you to use androidx imports, for example:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

It may need to add implementetion to your `dependencies {}`block inside build.gradle(app module) file:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

And then use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.